# Как удалить знак из вложенного (двууровнего) массива

Tags: php

Добрый день. Для обычного массива конструкция ниже работает (удаляет точки):

```
<?php
$temp = array (".com",".in",".aus",".cz");
print_r($temp);
$temp = preg_replace("/[.]/", "", $temp );
print_r($temp);
?>
```

А как удалить из вложенного массива тоже самое (допустим точки)? вот часть этого массива с 452 элементами как массивы:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 452
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Проектировщик
                )

            [0] => title
            [telephonenumber] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 10499
                )

            [1] => telephonenumber
            [displayname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Иванов Иван
                )

            [2] => displayname
            [department] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Отдел развития
                )

            [3] => department
            [mail] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => i.ivanov@mk.ru
                )

            [4] => mail
            [count] => 5
            [dn] => CN=Иванов Иван Владимирович,OU=Administrators,OU=Departments,OU=Отделы,OU=Office,DC=bam,DC=loc
        )

    [1] => Array
...
```

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` вам в помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вариант](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b07212de27827def173515a46c6baaf003f3075)

```
$arr = [['title'=>[".com"]],[".in",".aus",".cz"]];

array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$val, $key){
    $val = str_replace('.', '', $val);
});

var_dump($arr);
```